# Is it possible to generate random set of numbers that multiply together to give a certain number?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, logic

Is there an algorithm that could break down a number into a ***random set*** of single digit numbers that if multiplied together, end up being the same number given?

```
generatePossibility(number, size = 8)
```

> Note that it should not give back the same numbers every time I pass in the same number.

Eg: If I have pass in the number `940800`, it will generate any of below (size 11):

- `[5, 8, 7, 7, 1, 1, 1, 2, 5, 8, 6]`
- `[3, 4, 1, 2, 4, 5, 5, 8, 7, 7, 1]`
- `[8, 3, 8, 5, 2, 7, 5, 2, 7, 1, 1]`
- etc.

*The numbers don't have to be unique.

---

> **Update**

I realized that not all numbers are possible in this case. However, in my case, since I am the one setting the number (not a free input by any user), so I would like to know an algorithm that can break one number down into a certain size of an array of single digits.

My current algorithm is very inefficient and not pretty:

Eg: the number is 940,800

1. Generate an array of random single digits (excluding 0) that multiply up to 940,800
2. If the size is less than 8, add the rest of the space with 1
3. If the size is greater than 8, try removing the 1s
4. If the size is greater than 8, try to reduce it down by removing double 2 or double 3
5. If the size is greater than 8, this set of random digits is not possible.
6. Generate a new set of digits

```js
function isPrime(num) {
  for(var i = 2; i < num; i++)
    if(num % i === 0) return false;
  return num > 7; // Return any prime number that is not single digit
}

function shuffle(array) {
  // Shuffle the array
  return array.sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5);
}

function randomInt() {
  // returns 1 - 9
  return Math.floor((Math.random() * 9) + 1);
}

function removeElement(array, elem) {  
  const index = array.indexOf(elem);
  if (index > -1) {
      array.splice(index, 1);
  }
}

const shrink = (array, number) => {
  removeElement(array, number);
  removeElement(array, number);
  array.push(number * number);
  return array;
}

const expand = (array, number) => {
  array.push(number);
  array.push(number);
  removeElement(array, number * number);
  return array;
}

const getRandomDigits = (number, size) => {
  let remaining = number;
  const list = [];
  while (remaining !== 1) {
    if (isPrime(remaining)) {
      return `Unable to proceed, stuck at prime number ${remaining}`;
    }
    const randomNumber = randomInt();
    if (Number.isInteger(remaining / randomNumber)) {
      // Possible number, save it into the list
      list.push(randomNumber);
      // Update the remaining
      remaining /= randomNumber;
    }
  }
  return list;
}

const adjustSize = (array, size) => {
  // sort the array in ascending order
  let remaining = array.sort((a, b) => a - b);
  
  // if size is lower than desired size
  // find count of 4, if there is one, split them into double 2
  while (remaining.length < size && remaining.find(e => e === 4)) {
    remaining = expand(remaining, 2);
  }
  // find count of 9, if there is one, split them into double 3
  while (remaining.length < size && remaining.find(e => e === 9)) {
    remaining = expand(remaining, 3);
  }
  // add rest of the space with 1
  while (remaining.length < size) {
    remaining = remaining.push(1);
  }
  
  // If remaining has number "1", we can simply remove them
  while (remaining.length > size && remaining.includes(1)) {
    remaining.shift();
  }
  // combine possible integers
  // find count of 2, if there are two, combine them into single 4
  while (remaining.length > size && remaining.filter(e => e === 2).length > 1) {
    remaining = shrink(remaining, 2);
  }
  // find count of 3, if there are two, combine them into single 9
  while (remaining.length > size && remaining.filter(e => e === 3).length > 1) {
    remaining = shrink(remaining, 3);
  }
  // the given number is impossible
  while (remaining.length > size) {
    return `Couldn't generate, please try again! Size: ${remaining.length}`;
  }
  
  // possible
  return remaining;
}

let endResult = null;
let failedAttempt = 0;

while (!endResult && failedAttempt < 100) {
  const randomDigits = getRandomDigits(940800, 12);
  
  if (typeof randomDigits === 'string') {
    console.error(randomDigits);
    failedAttempt += 1;
    continue;
  }
  
  const attempt = adjustSize(randomDigits, 12);
  
  if (typeof attempt === 'string') {
    console.error(attempt);
    failedAttempt += 1;
    continue;
  }
  // Found it
  if (Array.isArray(attempt)) {
    endResult = shuffle(attempt);
  }
}

console.log('Failed attempt', failedAttempt);
console.log('Succeeded Result', endResult.join(','));
```

It kinda works, but it's ugly.

Comment: A random set of *single digit* factors for any given number? There is no such algorithm.     Any number with one or more prime factors that are 11 or greater cannot be broken down in such a way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Naive implementation partially based on @CertainPerformance suggestion

```js
function findPrimeFactors(num) {
  var primeFactors = [];
  while (num % 2 === 0) primeFactors.push(2), num = num / 2;
  for (var i = 3; i <= Math.sqrt(num); i++)
    while (num % i === 0) primeFactors.push(i), num = num / i;
  if (num > 2) primeFactors.push(num);
  return primeFactors;
}

function generatePossibility(number, size) {
  var factors = findPrimeFactors(number).sort().reverse();
  var ret = new Array(size).fill(1);
  for (i = 0; i < factors.length; i++) {
    var indexes = new Array();
    ret.filter((a, idx) => {
      if (a * factors[i] < 10)
        indexes.push(idx);
    });
    var randIdx = Math.floor(Math.random() * (indexes.length > 0 ? indexes.length : size));
    if (indexes.length > 0)
      ret[indexes[randIdx]] *= factors[i];
    else
      ret[randIdx] *= factors[i];
  }
  return ret;
}
var possibilities = generatePossibility(940800, 8);
console.log(possibilities.join(","));
console.log(possibilities.reduce((a, b) => a * b));
```

---

Getting the threshold (minimum array size of single digit combination of factors) of a number:

```js
function findPrimeFactors(num) {
  var primeFactors = [];
  while (num % 2 === 0) primeFactors.push(2), num = num / 2;
  for (var i = 3; i <= Math.sqrt(num); i++)
    while (num % i === 0) primeFactors.push(i), num = num / i;
  if (num > 2) primeFactors.push(num);
  return primeFactors;
}

function getThreshold(num) {
  var factors = findPrimeFactors(num).sort().reverse();
  if (factors.filter(a => a > 10).length > 0) return -1;
  var ret = [factors[0]];
  factors = factors.slice(1);
  while (factors.length > 0) {
    if (ret[ret.length - 1] * factors[0] > 10)
      ret.push(factors[0]);
    else
      ret[ret.length - 1] *= factors[0];
    factors = factors.slice(1);
  }
  return ret.length;
}

console.log(getThreshold(940800));
```

Comment: This is not what the OP wants, the factors must be single digits.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I've updated the code, please have a look at it, as the discussion went it is possible only for a few numbers and a given size

Answer (score 2):

First count up the prime factors of the number. For example, 940800 is:

```
2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 3 * 5 * 5 * 7 * 7
```

Then, to generate one of those random arrays, multiply any (or none) of the numbers of the above set together randomly, until you get the number of desired items in the array (here, 8). Eg, you could use `Math.random()` to randomly choose two indicies (without replacement). For example, say the indicies chosen were 0 and 1 - then you'd have

```
4 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 3 * 5 * 5 * 7 * 7
```

Maybe the next random indicies were 5 and 8 - then, you'd multiply indicies 5 and 8 together:

```
4 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 10 * 2 * 3 * 5 * 7 * 7
```

Repeat until you have the desired number of items. You might also shuffle the array before returning it, if you wanted.

To restrict the output array to single digits, in the process above, multiply only if the result is less than 10 - otherwise, re-choose indicies. (For some inputs, no solution will be possible, eg `generatePossibility(1000, 1)`.)

Comment: yeap, I agree that for some inputs there might be no solution. Probably I can handle that in the function. But for now, the number is set by me so I can make sure that it is possible at least, for example number 940800

Answer (score 0):

That is **not** possible. At least not with only **single digit** numbers.

*Why?*

Because what if, let's just say, one of the factors of a number is 13, 17, 19, 11... etc. or in other words, one of the factors is a double digit or triple digit prime number?

Comment: "Impossible is not French". This is obviously possible with certain numbers.

Comment: @YvesDaoust yup that is obvious. But a good solution is the one which works in every case. not just in a select few.

Comment: The OP says he is choosing numbers that work. So how do you solve ?

Comment: The OP didn't mention this in the original question. The question has been updated to include this detail. Now it is certainly "solvable"

Comment: Anyway, the statement "That is not possible" was false, as was evidenced by the OP's example.